# How to hide a checkbox that's in a fexible content box in ACF but not hide others

Tags: jquery, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, gutenberg-blocks

I’m using a flexible content on my block to add images to a post. In that flexible content, I have a checkbox to make that image a feature image. I’m wondering if there a way so that if a checkbox is selected in the first flexible content, it hides the checkbox in the rest. The problem is that they all have the same class (`.acf-field-5f8cf27f39a66`) and ID (`#three_img_plus_feature_img`) so when you hide that checkbox, it hides all of them. Any solution on how to solve this problem. Thanks.

Code I have so far:

```
$(document).on("click", "#three_img_plus_feature_img input", function () {
    if ($("#three_img_plus_feature_img input").is(":checked")) {
        $("#three_img_plus_feature_img label").css("display", "none");
    } else {
        $("#three_img_plus_feature_img label").css("display", "block");
    }
});
```

The HTML looks like this. It's the same for each item added, so if there are two items they all look the same.

```
<div id="three_img_plus_feature_img" class="acf-field acf-field-checkbox acf-field-5f8cf27f39a66" data-name="three_img_plus_feature_img" data-type="checkbox" data-key="field_5f8cf27f39a66" data-conditions="[[{&quot;field&quot;:&quot;field_5f8cf27f39951&quot;,&quot;operator&quot;:&quot;!=empty&quot;}]]">
  <div class="acf-label"></div>
  <div class="acf-input">
      <input type="hidden" name="acf-block_6019b745d990c[field_5f8cf27e7c782 [6019b7a4d990e][field_5f8cf27f39a66]">
      <ul class="acf-checkbox-list acf-bl">
          <li><label class=""><input type="checkbox" id="acf-block_6019b745d990c-field_5f8cf27e7c782-6019b7a4d990e-field_5f8cf27f39a66-three_img_plus_set_feature_img" name="acf-block_6019b745d990c[field_5f8cf27e7c782][6019b7a4d990e][field_5f8cf27f39a66][]" value="three_img_plus_set_feature_img"> Set featured image</label></li>
      </ul>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a temporary class on the clicked one, use for identification. Maybe not the best way to do it, but it could work:

```js
$(document).on("click", "#three_img_plus_feature_img input", function () {
    $("#three_img_plus_feature_img").removeClass('current');
    $(this).closest("#three_img_plus_feature_img").addClass('current');

    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $("#three_img_plus_feature_img:not(.current) label").css("display", "none");
    } else {
        $("#three_img_plus_feature_img:not(.current) label").css("display", "block");
    }
});
```

Comment: That's great but when you uncheck it, it doesn't remove the `.current` class. So when you click on the checkbox, it adds the `.current` class but when you uncheck it, the `.current` class remains.

Comment: `.current` is not used to identify the checked input, but to identify the *last clicked* input

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'll be using this as a starting point.